# Why is there ambiguity in this diamond pattern?

Tags: c++, diamond-problem

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A             { public: void eat(){ cout<<"A";} };
class B: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"B";} };
class C: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"C";} };
class D: public B,C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };

int main(){
    A *a = new D();
    a->eat();
}
```

I am not sure this is called diamond problem or not, but why doesn't this work?

*I have given the defination for `eat()` for `D`. So, it doesn't need to use either `B`'s or `C`'s copy (so, there should be no problem).*

**When I said, `a->eat()` (remember `eat()` is not virtual), there is only one possible `eat()` to call, that of `A`.**

Why then, do I get this error:

> 'A' is an ambiguous base of 'D'

---

What exactly does `A *a = new D();` mean to the compiler??

and

Why does the same problem not occur when I use `D *d = new D();`?

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine a slightly different scenario

```
class A             { protected: int a; public: void eat(){ a++; cout<<a;} };
class B: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<a;} };
class C: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<a;} };
class D: public B,C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };

int main(){
    A *a = new D();
    a->eat();
}
```

If this would work, would it increment the `a` in `B` or the `a` in `C`? That's why it's ambiguous. The `this` pointer and any non-static data member is distinct for the two `A` subobjects (one of which is contained by the `B` subobject, and the other by the `C` subobject). Try changing your code like this and it will work (in that it compiles and prints "A")

```
class A             { public: void eat(){ cout<<"A";} };
class B: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"B";} };
class C: public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"C";} };
class D: public B, public C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };

int main(){
    A *a = static_cast<B*>(new D());
      // A *a = static_cast<C*>(new D());
    a->eat();
}
```

That will call `eat` on the `A` subobject of `B` and `C` respectively.

Comment: @Johannes Schaub - litb: okay, I understand what you said. But why does the same problem not occur when I use `D *d = new D();`

Comment: @cambr, name lookup stops when you do `d->eat()` in the scope of `D` since it finds `eat` in `D`. It will not touch the `eat` in `A`, `B` or `C` and won't try to call them. So there is no conversion to `A` done in that case, and thus no ambiguity raises up.

Comment: If you would try `d->A::eat()` by trying to call `eat` on `A`, you would get the same problem again since it will try to convert `D*` down to an `A*`.

Comment: So, whn I do `A *a = new D();` a new object is created (of type `D`) and then a pointer of type `A` stores the address of this object. Is there a problem yet? Suppose I do not call `eat()`, this is all what happens (creation of an object and assiging of pointer). So, where is the problem in those two steps?

Comment: @combr, a pointer of type `A*` does *not* store the address of that object, but the address of one of the `A` objects. The ambigity arises as a choice of the A objects to point to.

Answer (score 6):

The diamond results in TWO instances of A in the D object, and it is ambiguous which one you are referring to - you need to use virtual inheritance to solve this:

```
class B: virtual public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"B";} };
class C: virtual public A   { public: void eat(){ cout<<"C";} };
```

assuming that you actually only wanted one instance. I also assume you really meant:

```
class D: public B, public C { public: void eat(){ cout<<"D";} };
```

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: "copies of `A` in the final object" Why would I copy A in the final object??

Comment: @cambr I was using "copy" to mean "instance" - I've changed it.

Comment: @Neil Butterworth: Also, I have defined `eat()` explicitly in D. So, it doesn't need to use copies/instance from either `B` or `C`.

Comment: @cambr This has nothing to do with the eat() function - try commenting out the call to it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the compile error is on the "A *a = new D();" line, not on the call to "eat".

The problem is that because you used non-virtual inheritance, you end up with class A twice: once through B, and once through C. If for example you add a member m to A, then D has two of them: B::m, and C::m.

Sometimes, you really want to have A twice in the derivation graph, in which case you always need to indicate which A you are talking about. In D, you would be able to reference B::m and C::m separately.

Sometimes, though, you really want only one A, in which case you need to use [virtual inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html).

Answer (score 2):

For a truly unusual situation, Neil's answer is actually wrong (at least partly).

With **out** virtual inheritance, you get two separate copies of `A` in the final object.

"The diamond" results in a single copy of `A` in the final object, and is produced *by* using virtual inheritance:

[image]

Since "the diamond" means there's only *one* copy of `A` in the final object, a reference to `A` produces no ambiguity. Without virtual inheritance, a reference to `A` could refer to either of two different objects (the one on the left or the one on the right in the diagram).

Comment: You have drawn an object diagram - my "wrong" answer was referring to the inheritance graph, which is a diamond.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Why does the same problem not occur when I use `D *d = new D();`? In that case also, an object of type `D` is being created and the same problems should occur.

Comment: @cambr:because `A *a = new D();` can't decide which `A` sub-object to point at. With `D *d=new D();`, it's going to point at the `D` object not one of the two `A` subjects, so there's no question about where it should point.

Comment: +1 for the nice diagram, I think it's the best way to **show** the two `A` in case there is no `virtual` inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting isn't coming from calling `eat()` - it's coming from the line before.  It's the upcast itself that creates the ambiguity.  As Neil Butterworth points out, there are two copies of `A` in your `D`, and the compiler doesn't know which one you want `a` to point at.

Comment: @Mike: why do I have `copies of A in your D`. I have defined a seperate `eat()` for D.

Comment: It's not to do with `eat()` at all; the call `a->eat()` doesn't itself care what classes are derived from `A` (as you say, `eat` is non-virtual) - it will always call `A::eat`.  As @Neil says, remove the call to `eat` and you still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**You want:** (Achievable with virtual inheritance)

> D
>      /  \
>   B   C
>      \  /
>       A

**And not:** (What happens without virtual inheritance)

> D
>       /   \
>     B   C
>     |     |
>     A     A

Virtual inheritance means that there will be only 1 instance of the base `A` class not 2.

Your type `D` would have 2 vtable pointers (you can see them in the first diagram), one for `B` and one for `C` who virtually inherit `A`.  `D`'s object size is increased because it stores 2 pointers now; however there is only one `A` now.

So `B::A` and `C::A` are the same and so there can be no ambiguous calls from `D`.  If you don't use virtual inheritance you have the second diagram above.  And any call to a member of A then becomes ambiguous and you need to specify which path you want to take.

[Wikipedia has another good rundown and example here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)